# Does draft evasion sound like a valid reason for applying for a US visa outside your home country?

Tags: visas

You can apply for a US visa in so called "third country" if you have sufficient reasons for doing so. Does evasion from a military service while pursuing a PhD in US sounds like a valid reason for not entering home country? For example, my home country does not really care about pursuing a PhD at foreign university and can grab you any time if you are unlucky enough. I did not receive an official request to enroll there, yet, because I am, well, out of their reach :) so I am not considered criminal, nor I break any law. But I do not want to risk receiving it by visiting home country.

Comment: That seems like it would be an "up to the consular officer" type scenario. Try calling the embassy in question.

Comment: Most countries are happy to process a visa application filed in the applicant's country of _residence_. Do you have an indication that the US demands them to be filed in countries of _nationality_?

Comment: Without considering your country's specific situation, it looks bad. You want consideration because you want to violate your country's law - this is an indication that you may violate US law too.